# phpThumb creating corrupted/oversized thumbnails

Tags: php, phpthumb

I'm having a very strange problem with the phpThumb library, for some reason when the thumbnails are generated they are being created very large in size (550k for a 150x65 image) and in many cases do not load at all. I have narrowed the issue down to the phpThumb library but I am unsure of what the actual problem is. Here is an example of one of the images: http://www.justsunnies.com.au/image/product/small/nitro_cr-c.jpg

Any help would be much appreciated as I am at my wits end as to why this problem is occurring.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use timthumb.php if would like

```
<img src="<?php echo path/to/timthumb.php?src="path"&h=100&w=100&q=500 ?>"/>
```